# client.Go retry on timeout expired

Tags: go, timeout, rpc, goroutine

I try to write a retry mechanism for rpc.Go.

```
func getMessage(config Configuration) (b bool, s string) {
    var timer *time.Timer
    req := RequestGetMessage{Topic: config.Topic}
    reply := ResponseGetMessage{}
    client, _ := rpc.Dial("tcp", config.Addr)
    try := 0
    for try < config.MaxRetry {
        call := client.Go("Server.GetMessage", req, &reply, nil)
        timer = time.NewTimer(time.Duration(config.RTimeout) * time.Millisecond)
        select {
        case <- call.Done:
            if call.Error == nil {
                if reply.Ok {
                    replyAck := ResponseAck{}
                    client.Call("Server.SendAck", RequestAck{Id: reply.Id}, &replyAck)
                    if replyAck.Ok {
                        client.Close()
                        return true, reply.Value
                    } else {
                        client.Close()
                        continue
                    }
                } else {
                    fmt.Printf("No message about this topic!\n")
                    client.Close()
                    return false, ""
                }
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("Error: %s\n", call.Error)
                client.Close()
                return false, ""
            }
        case <-timer.C:
            client.Close()
            try++
            client, _ = rpc.Dial("tcp", config.Addr)
            fmt.Printf("Timeout expired! Retry n: %d\n", try)
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("Max Retry exceed\n")
    client.Close()
    return false, ""
}
```

I'm testing the timeout, but after the first timeout expired the client is connected but it always gets timeout expired check! I tried to substitute `case <-timer.C:` with `case <-time.After(time.Duration(config.RTimeout) * time.Millisecond)` but nothing has changed.
What is the correct way to implement a timeout for rpc.Go?

Comment: Does this work without the timer? What is config.RTimeout set to? Also please check the error returned by rpc.Dial (ignoring them can hide a lot of issues).

Comment: I test this in local and it works. I set it to 500, I force the server to wait 2 seconds (by using a break point on the IDE) to check if the timer works. In the first place it seems to work, but after the first timeout the case in the select relative to the timeout is always true.

Comment: So what you are saying is that you stop the server (using a break point) and the client times out (pausing server for 2 seconds would cause approx four timeouts) but when you allow the server to run again (removing the breakpoint) the client continues to timeout? I suspect your debugging technique might be causing issues (the breakpoint will probably stop multiple go routines; not just the first one). Try adding logging in your server so it outputs when it has responded...